# PHP SQL - SELECT all versions but the highest one

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble selecting all versions, just not the last version in my database using SQL.

This is what my database looks like:

```
id | titleid | version
----------------------
1  | TEST1   | 1.27
2  | TEST1   | 1.28
3  | TEST1   | 1.29
4  | TEST1   | 1.30
5  | TEST2   | 1.05
6  | TEST2   | 1.06
7  | TEST2   | 1.07
8  | TEST2   | 1.08
```

I want to SELECT the records 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 since they're not the highest version.

I've tried searching SO but I can't seem to find anyone having the same issue as me.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: yep - `SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.version < (select max(t2.version) from t t2 where t2.titleid = t.titleid);
```

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for! Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With EXISTS:

```
select * from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where titleid = t.titleid and version > t.version
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ORDER BY, LIMIT & OFFSET

It wasn't mentioned, and while not the most performance oriented solution

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

It is the simplest.

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r1eEHfeuV3P3q6qTGyEHRf/0)

Sorting can be a real performance killer.  So of course make sure to index that version column.  For very simple applications it should be fine.  If however you have like a zillion rows, this is probably not the best choice.

I found exists to be quite fast, but alas that was taken already.

**UPDATE**

I read the question as wanted the next to highest version.  But you can get all but the highest, all you just need a really big limit like `PHP_INT_MAX` for example.

```
  //'SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT '.PHP_INT_MAX.' OFFSET 1'
 SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 1
```

**PHP_INT_MAX** is a predefined constant whos value is the maximum integer that the operating system can handle (32bit vs 64bit systems etc..).  So if that is not big enough ... lol ... nothing ever will be.

Comment: It is the simplest answer maybe for another question.